# Initial conditions and there justification

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Is this possible to have a variable initial condition in partial differential equations?
For example initial conditions of the type: $$\varPhi(x,0)=f(x)=x$$
what is the valid justification for this?

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, you can feel free to introduce the conditions of the form $\varPhi(p(x,y),q(x,y))=f(x,y)$ , the only things are that whether those conditions when substitute into the PDE may have no solution.

Comment: let me be specific for example for a parabolic pde i choose initial condition $p(x, 0)=x$, and i derived the solution. If some one ask me why you use $p(x, 0)=x$, it should be $p(x, 0)=x_0$, some constant not a vector. Then what should be the answer to that question?

Answer (score 1):

PDEs, and in paticular the 1st order ones, tell us how a function is changing in one direction, not in every direction. Hence, in order to know what the function looks like, we need to know how it changes in the remaining directions, i.e.,

$$
u_x+u_y=0,
$$

tells us that $u$ is constant on each straight line of the form
$$
x-y=c,
$$
and hence it only depends of the $c$, thus in order to get a formula for $f$ we need to know how it looks like, for example, on a line intersecting all of them, i.e. $y=0$. If we prescribe $f$ on $y=0$, as
$$
f(x,0)=h(x),
$$
$h$ smooth, then we get $f(x,y)=h(x-y)$.

Comment: so answer to my question is yes?
if someone ask why you use f(x)=x, then what should be the answer?
I want to understand this, that what is the justification of using initial condition?

Comment: @Malik: This only relates to source rather than mathematics(e.g. the problem given).

Answer (score 1):

There are many existence and uniqueness theorems, for various sorts of differential equations, and they tend to be of the form: "For any differential equation of a specified sort and any additional conditions of a specified sort, there exists a unique solution."  Those additional conditions, which are often initial conditions or boundary conditions, are, in my opinion, the real "meat" of the theorem. They tell you how far the differential equation is from completely describing a solution; in other words, they tell you how much additional information, beyond the differential equation, is needed in order to make the solution unique.  What sorts of additional conditions are needed here will depend on various things, like the number of variables, the order of the equation, whether the equation is hyperbolic or elliptic or something else, etc.  So the answer to "what is the justification for using initial condition[s]?" is: To complement the information in the differential equation just enough to ensure the uniqueness of the solution (without imposing too many requirements and thereby jeopardizing existence of solutions).  Figuring out which sorts of initial (or boundary, or ...) conditions are appropriate for which sorts of differential equations is in general non-trivial and is an essential part of the theory of differential equations.